# grep awk ignore character

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to grep the value of "option dhcp-server-identifier" which is 192.168.75.1;

I'm not sure how to ignore the semicolon "**;**" at the end of IP address.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases
lease {
interface "eth0";
fixed-address 192.168.75.54;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 192.168.75.1;
option dhcp-lease-time 4294967295;
option dhcp-message-type 5;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.75.1,8.8.8.8;
option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.75.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.75.255;
option host-name "centos-64-x86-64";
option domain-name "cs2cloud.internal";
renew 1 2081/12/15 18:43:55;
rebind 2 2132/12/30 03:09:24;
expire 6 2150/01/03 21:58:02;
}
```

I have tried the following

```
grep  dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases | awk '{print $3}'
```

result is 192.168.75.1;

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F" |;" '/dhcp-server-identifier/ {print $3}' /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases
192.168.75.1
```

Comment: +1 but ` |;` should be `[ ;]` for clarity, robustness, etc. A minor detail though.

Comment: @EdMorton Can you explain why `[ ;]` is more robust than `" |;"`? I thought it was the same. First means any characters in the square brackets. Second means space or `;`.

Comment: `a|b` means "RE a or RE b` while '[ab]' means `character a or character b`. Imagine the poster decides in future they only want the first section of the IP address so instead of `192.168.75.1` they just want `192`. They might change your script to be `awk -F" |." '/dhcp-server-identifier/ {print $3}'` and then be surprised when it fails due to `.` being an RE metacharacter. Whereas if you'd started with `-F'[ ;]'` they could simply change that to `-F'[ .]'` and it'd work as expected.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your explanation.  I know that you have to escape the `.`. I see your point and the pitfall. :)

Answer (score 3):

What about `awk` function `substr` :

```
~ $ echo "Hello My Friend!" | awk '{print substr($3,0,length($3)-1)}'
Friend
```

### Note about AWK

Awk is a really powerful and complete programming langage. If you find yourself using it more than once every couples of day, you could really benefit in your every day bash working flow by learning more of it (especially the regular expression handling part).

Source : [The AWK Manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html)

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/awk/

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if you're grepping to awk, you can simply use awk. The following are equivalent:

```
$ grep  dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases | awk '{print $3}'
$ awk  '/dhcp-server-identifier/ {print $3}' /var/lib/dhclients/dchclicent-eth0.leases
```

Your issue is that the semicolon appears on the end of the name. Instead of simply printing `$3`, we can use awk's `substr` function to remove that final character. Here's the reference to awk's manpage:

> **substr(s, m, n)**
>      the n-character substring of s that begins at position m counted from 1.
>
> **length** the length of its argument taken as a string, or of $0 if no argument.

So, we need the substring of `$3` from the first position (1), to the length of `$3` minus that last character, so we need to go from the first character to `length ($3) - 1`:

```
substr($3, 1, length($3) - 1)
```

That should do it:

```
$ awk  '/dhcp-server-identifier/ {print substr($3, 1, length($3) - 1)}' /var/lib/dhclients/dchclicent-eth0.leases
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*option dhcp-server-identifier \(.*\);/\1/p' file
```

---

With `grep` and `egrep`:

```
grep 'option dhcp-server-identifier' file  | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

---

Output:

```
192.168.75.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep  dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d';' -f1
```

Command explanation : Get lines that have ' dhcp-server-identifier'. Split by space, and show me 3rd selection. Split by ';' and show me first selection.

hek2mgl answer is one that I prefer to use; but for a beginner I usually suggest simpler tools than sed.

Comment: I remember that times when `cut` was the tool of choise for me too :).. +1 for *just getting it work* (that's what counts :) `sed` or generally spoken POSIX regexes aren't that hard. Try to get the Oreilly `Sed and Awk`

Answer (score 0):

**awk** version:

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '/dhcp-server-identifier/ {print $(NF-1)}' /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases
```

Using NF-1 is safer, just in case you have more whitespaces.

**perl** version:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/^.*dhcp-server-identifier +([0-9.]+);$/$1/' /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases
```

I think that is the safest 1-liner possible.

**sed** version from **hek2mgl** is good too.